# Text table model which allows add/remove columns without editing code

Tags: python, django

I want to create a model which allow user to store information within table representation. The main goal I want to achieve is to allow possibility of manual altering table, such as remove/add column, without editing code.

I can not find out how to create an elegant model for this purpose. Could you please help?

Comment: You're using the wrong tools then.

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with the model. You can give the user permission to edit/delete the data and then you need to write the views to do so.

Comment: It sounds like you want the user to be able to edit objects as they could in a JSON-like document storage system such as MongoDB. Investigate if a noSQL system can meet your needs.

Comment: See: http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html

Comment: I disagree with @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that you are using the wrong tools, but I rather think you are asking the wrong question. If you want people to be able to add arbitrary data, then you need to identify which data types you want them to be able to add, and make a model for that. Models are for modelling your needs ;)

Comment: Ex. I have table User with columns id, name. I want to be able to insert/delete rows and add/remove columns (ex. age, last_name) without editing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not make some kind of on-the-fly table altering system. That's sounds like an insane path... instead you can model a table layout with the data types, you need.

For instance:

```
INTEGER, FLOAT, TEXT = range(3)

class Table(models.Model):
    columns = models.ManyToManyField('TableColumn')

class TableColumn(models.Model):
    name = ...
    data_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[(INTEGER, 'Integer'), ...])

class TableRow(models.Model):
    order = ...
    column = models.ForeignKey('TableColumn')
    value_float = ...
    value_text = ...
    value_integer = ...

    def get_value(self):
        if self.column.data_type == INTEGER:
            return self.value_integer
```